# submit() event not firing on form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the submit button of a form after it is submitted to prevent double posting. While I can disable the button, I can't get the form to actually submit as well.

Here's the jQuery:

```
// Disable submit button after click to prevent double posting
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_pin :submit').on('click', function (e) {

        $(this).prop('disabled', true);    

    });
});
```

This will successfully disable the button, but that's it.

I've tried adding `$(this).submit()` after the .prop() but it still doesn't do anything.

The HTML is just:

```
<form action="http://example.com/add" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="add_pin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
// input fields
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Pin" class="radius button">
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `$('#add_pin :submit')` select a `form`? If not, try `$('#add_pin :submit')[0].form.submit()`

Comment: I don't believe you would be able to call `submit()` if you're disabling it first. You could try to call `submit()` before you set it to disabled. Or you could perhaps try the `one()` method defined here: http://api.jquery.com/one/.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, actually: `submit` event IS fired when you write the code like that. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/vEvzp/). But it's better to use `submit` handler indeed.

Comment: I wonder though, aren't you trying to submit the files here? If so, can't you show the full code - or at least the 'files-related' part?

Comment: @raina77ow Not sure I'm following you. What full code are you talking about? The full HTML form with all the inputs or the PHP that handles the file uploading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to use the form's `onsubmit` event instead of the submit button's `click` event because `onsubmit` will handle submissions from the enter key as well as the submit button being clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#add_pin').submit(function(){
        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    });

});
```